# In C++ - is it possible to compare volatile shared_ptr to nullptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, volatile

It seems like the `volatile` comparison functions in `shared_ptr` implementation do not exist.

Does it even make sense to exist?

Comment: Note that `volatile` is not a portable thread synchronisation mechanism (though arguably in some environments it might be sufficient). `volatile` usually is used in conjunction with memory mapped I/O and similar mechanisms, which would be a strange place for a `shared_ptr`. Maybe you should clarify *why* you would have a volatile shared_ptr.

Comment: @peterchen http://cxx.isvolatileusefulwiththreads.com/

Comment: @MikeVine: Excellent! Got to remember that link. (And check it daily, in case it changes)

Comment: @draif-kroneg please accept an answer if you think it answers the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Essentially no, the standard doesn't cater for [comparisons](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp) or [boolean conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_bool) on a `volatile shared_ptr`.

The [following fails](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb6786e678db28f1) to compile...

```
auto main() -> int {
    volatile shared_ptr<int> a;
    if (a == nullptr) // fails
        ; // empty
    if (a) // fails
        ; // empty
}
```

You could cast the `volatile` off (via. a `const_cast`), but I'm not sure that will have the desired outcome. From the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast):

> Modifying a `const` object through a non-`const` access path and referring to a `volatile` object through a non-`volatile` glvalue result in undefined behavior.

In more general terms, in not marking member methods as `volatile`, the class or library implementors are effectively saying "this is not intended to be use as a `volatile` object" - if it were, then the appropriate methods or overloads would provide for `volatile` objects. Similarly, this applies to `const`, in marking members as `const`, they are saying "this class can be used as a `const` object.

Why is the `volatile` needed, what external sources could be modifying the `shared_ptr` "without the knowledge of the compiler" (this is one of the uses of [`volatile`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv))? If there are threading issues, then you would be better served with one the thread library utilities, or if the requirement is simply turning off optimisations, various compilers have mechanisms for this already (pragmas etc.).

Comment: Good point, though I believe using std::atomic is perfectible over volatile with C++11 if we are indeed talking about threading.

Answer (score 3):

[Volatile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx) is just an indication to the compiler that the memory may change unexpectedly.  Turns off some optimizations.  Under the covers its just a memory address.

The shared pointer is just holding/managing the resource.  That said, since std::shared_ptr::get() isn't marked volatile, you cannot really use a shared_ptr to manage a volatile pointer in a accessible way.

I'd recommend using a naked pointer, and using scoped exit or the destructer to clean up after it.

If you are using volatile because the pointer may be modified by another thread, you may want to consider using std::atomic instead of volatile.  In threading workflows, before [std::atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic), pointers that were accessed from other threads were usually marked volatile.  That is no longer best practice.

Comment: actually volatile is not a suggestion.  One of the things it does do is: Every access (read or write operation, member function call, etc.) on the volatile object is treated as a visible side-effect for the purposes of optimization (that is, within a single thread of execution, volatile accesses cannot be reordered or optimized out.

Comment: Since that function does not have a volatile qualifier, it's impossible to call it with a volatile object....

Comment: @nathanOliver reworded it as you suggested.

Comment: @cpplearner: I stand corrected.  peterchen is right, std::shared_ptr isn't really written to handle volatile pointers.